# multiple highcharts on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

i designed simple page with the high charts and here charts are dynamically load when srolldown the web page like a goole+ and facebook, here i'm using the below highchart script for generate the chart but the problem is it load only one time and the rest of things is not loading when sroll down the web page,my code is below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
            // Create the chart

          window.chart0 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
       chart: {
            renderTo: 'container0',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 10,
            height:510
        }, 

                    title : {  text :'   ( IP:: )' },
                    xAxis: {  gapGridLineWidth: 0  }, 

                                            yAxis: [{ 
                             min:0
                             }],

                    series : [{
                            name : 'value',
                            type:'area',
     data :null,
                            tooltip: {
                                    valueDecimals: 2
                            },

    }],
            subtitle: {
                              text: 'MAX : 0 / MIN : 0 / AVG : 0.00 ',
                                     align: 'left',
                                     x: -1
                                     }
            });
    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/highstock.js"></script>

    <div id="container0" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
```

on above script

> window.chart0 = new Highcharts.StockChart({

for every scroll down it will set dynamically ( window.chart0,window.chart1,window.chart2.....)

Comment: Where is your code for the function that you call on scroll event ?

Comment: Is it possible to replicate it as live demo? DO you receive any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

here my code,

```
enter cod<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
             jQuery.ias({
            container : '.wrap', // main container where data goes to append
            item: '.item', // single items
            pagination: '.nav', // page navigation
            next: '.nav a', // next page selector
            loader: '<img src="css/loading.gif" style="height:150px; width:200px;"/> ', // loading gif
            triggerPageThreshold: 25 // show load more if scroll more than this
        });
    });
</script>

<body>  
  <div class="wrap">
   <div style="display: block;" class="item">

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function() {
         // Create the chart

      window.chart0 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
   chart: {
        renderTo: 'container0',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 10,
        height:510
    }, 

                title : {  text :'   ( IP:: )' },
                xAxis: {  gapGridLineWidth: 0  }, 

                                        yAxis: [{ 
                         min:0
                         }],

                series : [{
                        name : 'value',
                        type:'area',
 data :null,
                        tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 2
                        },

}],
        subtitle: {
                          text: 'MAX : 0 / MIN : 0 / AVG : 0.00 ',
                                 align: 'left',
                                 x: -1
                                 }
        });
});
       </script>
<script src="js/highstock.js"></script>

<div id="container0" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
            <a href='test.php?clientname=<?php echo $name;?>&p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
  </div>
   </div>
```